# ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification -- row level trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger to notify when an employee's name is changed.

```
 create or replace trigger name_change
 after update on employee_table
 for each row when (old.e_name != new.e_name);
 begin
 dbms_output.putline(:old.e_name || 'changed their name to' || :new.e_name);
 end;
```

Not sure where the error is coming from.

Comment: As well as the stray semicolon at the end for the `for` clause (which does get ORA-04079 in SQL\*Plus, but ORA-00911 in SQL Developer), it's `put_line` not `putline`. But you shouldn't rely on `dbms_output` - there's no way to tell if the caller will (or even can) display that. It's not really a notification if it won't be seen - and do you really want the updater to be notified (odd as they already know), or someone else?

Comment: @AlexPoole thank you! I use dbsm_output because that is what is taught in class. I guess it's more of a confirmation that the name has been updated than a notification.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no semicolon after `when (old.e_name != new.e_name)`